# Save loaded data from text file in MATLAB file

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a MATLAB program in which I read a text file using textscan and then store the data in corresponding arrays. It does that every run, and it takes about two minutes each time. I would like to know if there is a way to save the arrays after I loaded the data, and have the program remember them so I can read the data only once and save time while running. I looked into the load function, but I'm not sure if that's what I need.

Comment: Yes, [`save`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) and [`load`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) should be enough for this.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know there was a save function. It seems this is what I need.